# Adding a note to InputDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I am working on eclipse JFace GUI stuff.

I am reading some input from the user and able to validate using the validator as below.

```
     // creating input prompt
     InputDialog inputDialog = new InputDialog(parentShell, dialogTitle, dialogMessage, initialValue, validator);

     // Validator
     IInputValidator validator = new IInputValidator()
     {
        @Override
        public String isValid(String newName)
        {
            if (newName.isBlank())
            {
                return "Warning: Input is empty";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

What I want to implement is to add a note to the user which is not related to validation.

Basically the note is about describing what happens if the button OK is pressed (As shown in image).

[image]

Any help/idea will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this text going to change or is it fixed?

Comment: It is fixed text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a new dialog class extending `InputDialog` to do this overriding `createDialog` to add extra controls. Something like:

```java
public class InputDialogWithNote extends InputDialog
{
  private Label noteLabel;

  public InputDialogWithNote(final Shell parentShell, final String dialogTitle, final String dialogMessage, final String initialValue, final IInputValidator validator)
  {
    super(parentShell, dialogTitle, dialogMessage, initialValue, validator);
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent)
  {
    Composite body = (Composite)super.createDialogArea(parent);

    noteLabel = new Label(body,  SWT.LEAD);
    noteLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    return body;
  }
}
```

You will have to arrange some way to set the `noteLabel` field.

Comment: I am getting compiler error. "The method setLayoutData(GridData) is undefined for the type Label"

Comment: You are importing the wrong Label - it must be `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label`